# looking for a mysql_fetch_field equivalent in sqlsrv or any work around

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

Following snippet outputs the field names present in a `mysql` query:

```
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{

    $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
    echo  $field->name , ",";  
    //outputs something like ID,FirstName,OrderNbr etc..
}
```

Obviously this only works with a `mysql` result handle (`$result`).

How do you do the same thing when the statement handle is `sqlsrv`?

EDIT: We all pretty much know that mysql out, and mysqli in. But the question is not about that.

Comment: [`mssql_fetch_field`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-fetch-field.php)?

Comment: Using the mssql extension or PDO?

Comment: You should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons).

Comment: @Matt: These comment should be automatically added whenever someone uses the mysql extensions :-)

Comment: @ZombieHunter i'm surprised there's no meta question on this

Comment: I get a Call to undefined function mssql_fetch_field(). All my mssql work is done with sqlsrv_ way not the mssql_ way. I checked for the existence of `sqlsrv_fetch_field()` but there isn't.

Comment: @ZombieHunter I just added this as a feature request to meta.

Comment: @ZombitHunter [this was the response I received, almost immediately](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se).

Comment: @Matt: Well, this still needs to be added manually. I'd prefer a bot :-). But thanks for investigating

Comment: Hey Matt, what's a meta question anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the ZombieHunter's lead, here is the answer to my question.

Included here for those who might need it.

```
    foreach( sqlsrv_field_metadata($result) as $fieldMetadata)
    {
        echo $fieldMetadata['Name'] , ",";  
        //outputs something like ID,FirstName,OrderNbr etc..
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the database extension you're using:

- Using ext/mssql, the equivalent would be [`mssql_fetch_field()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-fetch-field.php).
- Using PDO, the equivalent would be
  [`PDOStatement::getColumnMeta()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php).

Comment: thank you nickb, but I get a `Call to undefined function mssql_fetch_field()` error. I forgot to mention in my question that all the microsoft sql work I deal with is done thru the sqlsrv_ way not the mssql_ way. I checked for the existence of sqlsrv_fetch_field() but there isn't. The solution must be based on sqlsrv_ methods or it won't work for me. I cannot get into the PDO now neither cause I'm working with a non PDO library - unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`sqlsrv_field_metadata()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc296197%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

As far as I can see there is nothing else available. Check the [API Reference on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc296152%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) for a complete list of all supported functions.